# How can we make seacrete / biorock grow faster?

Tags: materials

Seacrete is an interesting building material (precipitated limestone in seawater) but is quite slow to grow.

https://naturalbuildingblog.com/seacreteseamentbiorock/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biorock

With the purpose of making it grow as fast as possible, for the purpose of building structures, are the variables known (salinity, temperature, exact electric current, any others) that affect its rate of accretion/'growth' to boost the process, i.e., faster in cold or warmer water, salinity, etc.

I.e, have any known studies been made of the optimal conditions for fast seacrete accretion.

Comment: You might find some tips [here](https://repository.library.carleton.ca/downloads/qv33rx56d) and [here](https://repository.ipb.ac.id/jspui/bitstream/123456789/53405/1/1_biorock_b.pdf)...

Answer (score 1):

It is a calcarious deposit that builds up on steel with cathodic protection in seawater. Similar to limestone. It is desirable to reduce current needed for cathodic protection otherwise of no particular value that I have heard of.